# Using fast-csv while querying / creating mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

The code below does two things:

**1) First pause the parser, and query the user collection if the user doesn't exist then create the user.**

**2) Then finish by creating (saving) the stories documents from the original data uploaded, and resume the parser.**

When I run the code, all the documents except for one row is parsed and uploaded. (the file size doesn't matter, one row is always skipped).

If I run the checkLength function by itself, the file is uploaded and saved properly without issue.

**So my question is: Am I using callbacks correctly here?** My end goal is to run the checkLength function after findUsers has completed, then resume parsing. I'm guessing promises could be useful as well, but I don't want to jump too far ahead.

```
 let parser = csv
   .fromString(myFile, {
     renameHeaders: true,
     headers: headerArray,
     ignoreEmpty: true
 })

.on("data", function(data) {

  let checkLength = function() {
    data.endUser = user;
    stories.push(data);
    if (Story.length > 100) {
      Test.Story.create(stories, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      storiesTotalLength += stories.length;
      stories= [];          
    }
    parser.resume();
  }      

  let findUsers = function(callback) {
    User.findOne({
        name: data.endUser
      }, function(err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (results) {
       callback();
      }else{
        user = {
          name: data.endUser,
          _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
        }
        User.create(user, function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          callback();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  parser.pause();
  findUsers(checkLength);

})
.on("end", function() {

  Story.create(stories, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;        
  });

  res.render('pages/uploadpage', {
    message: (`${stories.length + storiesTotalLength} documents have been successfully uploaded. ${users.length} Total New Users`)
  });

});
```

Comment: I can't see what would be wrong, you maybe return a response too early so the response doesn't show the last record. You could try `res.render` in the `Story.create` callback.

Comment: Another thing I can think of is that the csv file's first line does not contain headers so the first line contains data. In that case I think you should omit `renameHeaders: true,` I think, not sure because documentation is kind of unclear about this.

Comment: I could not get it to work, but using the transform method and next seemed to work perfectly.